# ASP.NET links won't redirect to the right page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, hyperlink

From time to time I encounter issues linking to page in Visual Studio when working with ASP.NET application.

I create links to pages but they always redirect to the default one (Default.aspx)

- I trying various thing like deleting and recreate
- Rename the page
- Even If the page does not exist it still redirects to the defaults
  page.

My `Login.aspx` page is the same folder as `ForgotPassword.aspx` I create links like this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server"
               NavigateUrl="ForgotPassword.aspx">
             Forgot your password ?
</asp:HyperLink>
```

or

```
<a href="ForgotPassword.aspx">Forgot your password ?<a>
```

I am at loss to understand why such basic stuff would fail to work...
How can I solve this issue? Could this be a bug?

EDIT: 
The Url in the browser looks like this:

```
/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fForgotPassword.aspx
```

My webconfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: You might have a check on the ForgetPassowrd page. That redirect you back to default.aspx.. Check page load method of ForgetPassword page.

Comment: can you post your web.config, to me is more like an authentication issue, check on google chrome if you are hitting the right page and then getting a redirection...

Comment: have you tried? <authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this by adding the following to my web.config file:

```
  <location path="ForgotPassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you compile your web site?  If Visual Studio cannot find your ForgotPassword.aspx page, you should get a Warning in your Error List that says "File 'ForgotPassword.aspx' was not found."  Note that this will appear in the Error List tab, not the Output tab.

Assuming you are not getting this warning...hmm.  The only thing that pops into my head is maybe you have a default behavior specified?  If it cannot find the page specified in the link, you should get a 404.  If your website is hosted in IIS, you can specify behaviors when you get error messages, like 404s.  Maybe IIS is doing something where it redirects a 404 to go to a Default.aspx page?

Also, I just noticed you started off with "from time to time".  So that means this is an inconsistent error?  The links sometimes work, but sometimes they don't?  If that's the case, something is seriously wrong and it may be some sort of bug in Visual Studio, a plug-in, or something else.  Reinstall when all else fails!

Comment: That seems pretty bad then!  We should make sure Visual Studio can find this file.  It is possible that the file exists on disk, but maybe not so in Visual Studio.  When you have your solution open, do you see Login.aspx and ForgotPassword.aspx in the same location in your Solution Explorer?  If they are not at the same level in the Solution Explorer, this could explain why it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

What does your Authorization node look like in your Web.config?  My guess is that the path to your Forgot Password page is requiring an authenticated user.