# NoCache is not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, browser-cache

I used an Action Filter named [NoCache] to disable the access of login page after login by pressing the browser back button. The code is given below.

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Then i referred it in login page as shown below.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [NoCache]
        public ActionResult Index(Login objLogin)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Blood");
        }
```

But the result was unexpected. Instead of redirecting to Blood/Index action, the control transfered to the url : `http://localhost:4506/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fBlood`

How can i correct this ?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This probably related with Form Authentication feature. Do you need it? If not, just don't use it.

For more details, please refer to:
[How to remove returnurl from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716153/how-to-remove-returnurl-from-url)