# Remove ReturnUrl parameter from LoginPath

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-identity

As we always redirect logged in user to one page, there is no need for `ReturnUrl` parameter be added into `LoginPath` during redirection to login page.
This is not critical, as we just don't use it, but this would look leaner without it.

Tried already `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ReturnUrlParameter`, but setting it to an empty string does not help.

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
        .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
            .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
        .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login"),
        .ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
        .SlidingExpiration = True,
        .ReturnUrlParameter = ""})
```

This is different from 
[How to remove returnurl from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716153/how-to-remove-returnurl-from-url)
in two ways:

1. I am using Asp.Net Identity 2.2.2, not Forms Authentication
2. I am looking for a way to stop adding `ReturnUrl` parameter rather than removing it once is already added.

Comment: Can you add some code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove returnurl from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716153/how-to-remove-returnurl-from-url)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev So that one as well, it is about Forms Authentication, here I am talking about Asp.Net Identity 2.2.2. I am looking for some built in mechanism, to stop adding ReturnUrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        //HERE IS THE TRICK
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString.Value))
            return RedirectToAction("Login");

        return View();
    }
```